# Building GLEW with MinGW-64 in MSYS2 failing - make: i686-w64-mingw32-ld: Command not found

Tags: gcc, build, mingw, glew, msys2

I'm new to all this. The GLEW folder is on my Windows drive, and I'm trying to build it with MinGW-w64 from MSYS2 to use in an OpenGL program. The fresh MSYS2 install is fully up to date and is running from /MSYS2/mingw32.exe. The only extra packages installed into MSYS2 are git, mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc and base-devel.

```
$ make SYSTEM=linux-mingw-w64
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -DGLEW_NO_GLU -DGLEW_BUILD -O2 -Wall -W -Iinclude -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector  -o tmp/linux-mingw-w64/default/shared/glew.o -c src/glew.c
i686-w64-mingw32-ld -shared -soname libglew32.dll --out-implib lib/libglew32.dll.a     -o lib/glew32.dll tmp/linux-mingw-w64/default/shared/glew.o -nostdlib -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lkernel32
make: i686-w64-mingw32-ld: Command not found
make: *** [Makefile:122: lib/glew32.dll] Error 127
```

In windows I can look and find i686-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe located in \MSYS2\mingw32\bin\ but i686-w64-mingw32-ld is nowhere to be found within \MSYS2\

If I enter only "make", which I think is using a different SYSTEM= option, I get this:

```
$ make
gcc -fno-builtin -DGLEW_NO_GLU -DGLEW_BUILD -O2 -Wall -W -Iinclude -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector  -o tmp/mingw/default/shared/glew.o -c src/glew.c
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libglew32.dll -Wl,--out-implib,lib/libglew32.dll.a    -o lib/glew32.dll tmp/mingw/default/shared/glew.o -L/mingw/lib -nostdlib -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lkernel32
strip -x lib/glew32.dll
sed \
        -e "s|@prefix@|/usr|g" \
        -e "s|@libdir@|/usr/lib|g" \
        -e "s|@exec_prefix@|/usr/bin|g" \
        -e "s|@includedir@|/usr/include/GL|g" \
        -e "s|@version@|2.1.0|g" \
        -e "s|@cflags@||g" \
        -e "s|@libname@|glew32|g" \
        -e "s|@requireslib@|glu|g" \
        < glew.pc.in > glew.pc
gcc -fno-builtin -DGLEW_NO_GLU -DGLEW_STATIC -O2 -Wall -W -Iinclude -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector  -o tmp/mingw/default/static/glew.o -c src/glew.c
ar rv lib/libglew32.a tmp/mingw/default/static/glew.o
a - tmp/mingw/default/static/glew.o
C:\MSYS2\mingw32\bin\ar.exe: creating lib/libglew32.a
strip -x lib/libglew32.a
gcc -fno-builtin -DGLEW_NO_GLU -O2 -Wall -W -Iinclude -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector  -o tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o -c src/glewinfo.c
gcc -fno-builtin -O2 -Wall -W -Iinclude -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -o bin/glewinfo.exe tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o -Llib  -lglew32 -L/mingw/lib -nostdlib -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lkernel32
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `fprintf'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text+0x54): undefined reference to `fprintf'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text+0x5c): undefined reference to `strlen'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text+0x90): undefined reference to `fprintf'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text+0xb8): undefined reference to `fprintf'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text+0xed): undefined reference to `fprintf'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text+0x109): undefined reference to `fprintf'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text+0x111): undefined reference to `strlen'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text+0x12d): undefined reference to `fprintf'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text+0x152): undefined reference to `fprintf'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text+0x187): undefined reference to `fprintf'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text+0x1a4): undefined reference to `fprintf'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text+0x1ac): undefined reference to `strlen'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text+0x1dc): undefined reference to `fprintf'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text+0x1e9): undefined reference to `fflush'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text+0x1e46e): undefined reference to `sscanf'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text+0x1e492): undefined reference to `strcmp'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text+0x1e4aa): undefined reference to `strcmp'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text+0x1e4c9): undefined reference to `strcmp'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text+0x1e500): undefined reference to `strcmp'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text+0x1e51f): undefined reference to `strcmp'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text+0x1e544): more undefined references to `strcmp' follow
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text+0x1e596): undefined reference to `strtol'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text+0x1e5b5): undefined reference to `strcmp'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text+0x1e5df): undefined reference to `strcmp'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text+0x1e620): undefined reference to `memset'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text+0x1e716): undefined reference to `memset'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text+0x142): undefined reference to `fflush'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text.startup+0x1d): undefined reference to `__main'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text.startup+0x98): undefined reference to `fopen'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text.startup+0xba): undefined reference to `fprintf'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text.startup+0xcf): undefined reference to `fprintf'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text.startup+0xe4): undefined reference to `fprintf'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text.startup+0x10b): undefined reference to `fprintf'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text.startup+0x127): undefined reference to `fprintf'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text.startup+0x160): more undefined references to `fprintf' follow
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text.startup+0x177d): undefined reference to `_imp____acrt_iob_func'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text.startup+0x178f): undefined reference to `fclose'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text.startup+0x17af): undefined reference to `_imp____acrt_iob_func'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text.startup+0x17bf): undefined reference to `fprintf'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text.startup+0x17d3): undefined reference to `_imp____acrt_iob_func'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text.startup+0x17e3): undefined reference to `fprintf'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text.startup+0x1808): undefined reference to `_imp____acrt_iob_func'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text.startup+0x181c): undefined reference to `fprintf'
tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o:glewinfo.c:(.text.startup+0x1838): undefined reference to `_imp____acrt_iob_func'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:181: bin/glewinfo.exe] Error 1
```

So over on the GLEW git, it's [recommended](https://github.com/nigels-com/glew/issues/96) to fix this error that I modify the Makefile in a certain way, which I did. After that, if I run only "make", my /lib's are built, but my object files in /src are not there:

```
$ make
gcc -fno-builtin -DGLEW_NO_GLU -DGLEW_BUILD -O2 -Wall -W -Iinclude -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector  -o tmp/mingw/default/shared/glew.o -c src/glew.c
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libglew32.dll -Wl,--out-implib,lib/libglew32.dll.a    -o lib/glew32.dll tmp/mingw/default/shared/glew.o -L/mingw/lib -nostdlib -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lkernel32
strip -x lib/glew32.dll
sed \
        -e "s|@prefix@|/usr|g" \
        -e "s|@libdir@|/usr/lib|g" \
        -e "s|@exec_prefix@|/usr/bin|g" \
        -e "s|@includedir@|/usr/include/GL|g" \
        -e "s|@version@|2.1.0|g" \
        -e "s|@cflags@||g" \
        -e "s|@libname@|glew32|g" \
        -e "s|@requireslib@|glu|g" \
        < glew.pc.in > glew.pc
gcc -fno-builtin -DGLEW_NO_GLU -DGLEW_STATIC -O2 -Wall -W -Iinclude -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector  -o tmp/mingw/default/static/glew.o -c src/glew.c
ar rv lib/libglew32.a tmp/mingw/default/static/glew.o
a - tmp/mingw/default/static/glew.o
C:\MSYS2\mingw32\bin\ar.exe: creating lib/libglew32.a
strip -x lib/libglew32.a
gcc -fno-builtin -DGLEW_NO_GLU -O2 -Wall -W -Iinclude -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector  -o tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o -c src/glewinfo.c
gcc -fno-builtin -O2 -Wall -W -Iinclude -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -o bin/glewinfo.exe tmp/mingw/default/shared/glewinfo.o -Llib -lglew32 -L/mingw/lib  -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lkernel32
strip -x bin/glewinfo.exe
gcc -fno-builtin -DGLEW_NO_GLU -O2 -Wall -W -Iinclude -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector  -o tmp/mingw/default/shared/visualinfo.o -c src/visualinfo.c
gcc -fno-builtin -O2 -Wall -W -Iinclude -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -o bin/visualinfo.exe tmp/mingw/default/shared/visualinfo.o -Llib -lglew32 -L/mingw/lib  -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lkernel32
strip -x bin/visualinfo.exe
```

If I run "make SYSTEM=linux-mingw-w64" after the recommended fix, it gives the same error as it did before and nothing is built. I want to build with this option since I'm going to be compiling my OGL project that calls for GLEW, using MinGW-w64 32-bit.

Questions:

1. Why is i686-w64-mingw32-lb missing, and how can I obtain it?
2. Why does "make" without the SYSTEM= flag fail to build the .o files into /src but give no errors?

Comment: You have the *32bit* target *MinGW32* binaries. More details on https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/GeneralUsageInstructions (you can see there both toolchains). `SYSTEM=` makes the target to be *64bit*. the build error is because you don't have the *32bit* **host** *libc*. Regarding the file not found, maybe some dirs not in *${PATH}* or installation corrupt?

Comment: I'm confused. Here are a bunch of nooby questions:

1. What does "target" binary mean?

2. The "SYSTEM= " flag inherently causes the target (whatever a target is) to be 64 bit?

3. What is a host libc? What is a libc? I can Google these but I can't understand their descriptions within this context...

4. The file not found thing... I thought you said that was because I used the wrong target binaries or toolchain somethings... also, if I were to pick up a different build from that link, would it be 32-bit or 64? Those gcc versions are outdated (2013), should I "install" & update them?